# remove specific months from Datepicker

Tags: jquery, wordpress, datepicker

In wordpress i'm trying to remove specific months in datepicker, but my code it's not working.

```
    invalidMonths = [11,12,1,2];

function noInvalidMonths(date) {
    if(jQuery.inArray(date.getMonth()+1, invalidMonths)>-1){
        return [false, '']
    }
    return [true, ''];

}
jQuery(function($) {
    $("#date1").datepicker({
        minDate: 0,
        maxDate: null,
        dateFormat: 'MM dd, yy',
        beforeShowDay: noInvalidMonths
    });
});
```

Comment: nothing changed..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your function with following code,

```
function noInvalidMonths(date) 
{
    var month = date.getMonth();
    if (jQuery.inArray(month, invalidMonths) != -1) {
         return [false];
     }
     return [true];    
  }
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Please check your console and see if any javascript error. and of any error then let me know that

Comment: no errores on console and all moths showing. See the online link: http://www.cantresformentera.com/book-now/

Comment: This is contcatform 7 datepicker and you want to extend that field but you haven't add proper info first. Above method is working for date picker which is called like given way. Contact form 7 call within its js so you need to extend that one,

Answer (score 0):

Change like this. Note the increment of the month in the code, else you need to define as 'month-1' in the `invalidMonths` array.

```
var invalidMonths = [11,12,1,2];

function noInvalidMonths(date) 
{
    var month = eval(date.getMonth()+1); //increment by 1 since the months start from 0

    if (jQuery.inArray(month, invalidMonths) != -1) {
         return [false];
     }
     return [true];    
}

jQuery(function($) {
    $("#date1").datepicker({
        minDate: 0,
        maxDate: null,
        dateFormat: 'MM dd, yy',
        beforeShowDay: noInvalidMonths
    });
});
```

**UPDATE:**
Deactivate your 'Contact Form 7 Datepicker' plugin, change both the 'datepickers' in your contact form to just 'text' boxes. Add the following to your theme's 'functions.php'.

```
function wp_custom_enqueue_datepicker() {
    // Load the datepicker script (pre-registered in WordPress).
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-datepicker', array( 'jquery' ) );
    wp_register_style('jquery-ui', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css');
    wp_enqueue_style( 'jquery-ui' );   

    wp_add_inline_script( 'jquery-ui-datepicker', 'var invalidMonths = [11,12,1,2];  function noInvalidMonths(date)  {     var month = eval(date.getMonth()+1);   if (jQuery.inArray(month, invalidMonths) != -1) {          return [false];      }      return [true];     }  jQuery(function($) {     $("#date1,#date2").datepicker({         minDate: 0,         maxDate: null,         dateFormat: \'MM dd, yy\',         beforeShowDay: noInvalidMonths     });        var $date1 = $(\'#date1\'), $date2 = $(\'#date2\');     $date1.datepicker(\'option\', \'onSelect\', function(value){       $date2.datepicker(\'option\', \'minDate\', value);     }); });' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wp_custom_enqueue_datepicker' );
```

Comment: All dates of specified month(s) will be disabled - are everything showing enabled after using this code?

Comment: Only dates of specified month(s) will be disabled using this code and month(s) will be still shown. Can you post the screenshot in your question if not?

Comment: no errores on console and all moths showing. See the online link: http://www.cantresformentera.com/book-now/

Comment: The datepicker script already loading with the element names `$('input[name="date-775"]').datepicker()` around line 1269 and that's why new script not gets loading. Try insert `beforeShowDay: noInvalidMonths` to the initial script itself and remove the second separate script.

Comment: Check the 'UPDATE' section in the answer and let me know whether it helps.